# How to check if some column in JDBC table is null in Java

Tags: java, sql, database, netbeans, jdbc

I need to check if a field in my table is empty (null) and if so, do a specific task; if not, do something different. I have tried rs.wasNull() and got the error "wasNull() called with no data retrieved". Are there any other methods to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method? `rs.wasNull()` is the best way. But if you insist... Depending on the implementation of the JDBC driver (varies according to the vendor database), you can do the following:

```
Object decimalDigits = rs.getObject("DECIMAL_DIGITS");
if (decimalDigits == null) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to first get a value from `rs`, such as with `rs.getInt("col1")`, right before you call `rs.wasNull()`.

Comment: And you must call `rs.next()` before calling `rs.getInt()`.